# How do I support a variable JSON field of array(array,string) in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

all.

I'm trying to create a struct to hold the contents of an API call that has a certain structure, but not sure how to write it.

Here's one result from the API where I'm having issues coding the receiving struct for:

```
"10E": {
  "baseSetSize": 264, 
  "block": "Guilds of Ravnica", 
  "boosterV3": [
    [
      "rare", 
      "mythic rare"
    ], 
    "uncommon", 
    "uncommon", 
    "uncommon", 
    "common", 
    "common", 
    "common", 
    "common", 
    "common", 
    "common", 
    "common", 
    "common", 
    "common", 
    "common", 
    "land", 
    "marketing"
  ], 
  "cards": [ ... ]
}
```

The API lists the 'boosterV3' key as having the format `array(array, string)`. However, some the returned data contains an array of 16 strings, and at least one has an array of strings as it's first element.

I've tried using the following struct:

```
struct MtGSet : Codable {
    let name: String
    let baseSetSize: Int
    let block: String
    let boosterV3: [String]
    let cards: [MtGCard]
}
```

But running against the API with this generates this error:

```
[CodingKeys(stringValue: "boosterV3", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], 
debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Is it possible to write a data structure in Swift that would accept either 16 String values or 15 String values and 1 array of String for the `boosterV3` key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like the below. I am not testing this I just created by converting JSON to Swift. you can also do it by yourself, here it is https://app.quicktype.io/.

```
struct MtGSet : Codable {
    let name: String
    let baseSetSize: Int
    let block: String
    let boosterV3: [BoosterV3] // user [] of BoosterV3 instead of string
    let cards: [MtGCard]
}

enum BoosterV3: Codable {
    case string(String)
    case stringArray([String])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode([String].self) {
            self = .stringArray(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(BoosterV3.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for BoosterV3"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .stringArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
```